# Parsing XML with PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I've been looking around for a solution for this but can't find one anywhere.

I am trying to parse a `XML` file, but certain `TagNames` are missing from the `XML`. Some posts suggest using the object length but this doesn't work either.

```
if ($xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('image1')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->length > 0) {
    $product_image1 = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('image1')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
} else {
    $product_image1 = "";
}
```

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /home/s/public_html/import_xml.php on line 72
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object in
>   /home/s/public_html/import_xml.php on line 72

The error is because `<image1>` is missing from the XML.

Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: You need to make if statements to check if each item in the xml chain you are calling exists.

Comment: That is what I was trying to do with length > 0. So as that didn't work, how do I check if it exists? if isset ?

Comment: that's fine, but you can't use -> length if any of the parent nodes don't exist. you basically have to check every level of the tree to ensure that it actually exists.

Comment: Isset and just if ($xmlObjext->item($i)) for example. The problem is that you make a few references in a row in the same statement so you don't know which ->item() is the problem.

Comment: Marc B, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I've done it. Not sure if its "the best" way, but it works...

```
foreach ($xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('product')->item($i)->childNodes as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
        $nodes[] = $node->nodeName;
        echo "Processing node " . $node->nodeName . "<br />";
    }
}

if (in_array("name", $nodes)) {
    $product_name = $xmlObject->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
} else {
    $product_name = "";
}
```